# Android - Google Maps Api can't change default background color

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, background-color

My whole app design is based on dark colors, so I also customized Google Maps using [mapstyle.withgoogle.com](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) but when I start the `MapsActivity` the default Map Background color is still bright until it fully loads as you can see in this
[EXAMPLE GIF](https://i.gyazo.com/d17d9c2280490e6492591936106a9bc8.gif)

**This bright background also appears when I zoom out the first time after the Map is loaded!

Is there a way to change the color of that splash screen, background or Map placeholder(how can we call it)?

Here's my custom MapStyle that I created using [mapstyle.withgoogle.com](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

```
    [
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#a8d0c8"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#1a3646"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#4b6878"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#64779e"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#4b6878"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#98c1d9"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#293241"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#1a3646"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#283d6a"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#6f9ba5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#1d2c4d"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#023e58"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#3C7680"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#e1fbfc"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#98a5be"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#1d2c4d"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#ec5935"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#000000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#255763"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#b0d5ce"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#023e58"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#4e1507"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#98a5be"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#1d2c4d"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#283d6a"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.station",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#3a4762"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#5e82b3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#4e6d70"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Anyway, you can use workaround: show some `View` e.g. `ImageView` with your dark colors palette over your Google Map, and then hide it e.q. in `onCameraIdle()` listener when your map loaded and custom style applied.

Comment: Thank you mate for the help with RenderScript and the RGB problem. I found the solution based on your link. Awesome. It is not possible to send private messages here, but I just wanted to thank you.